# How to interact with a server-side Java program via HTTP?

Tags: servlets, amazon-web-services

This probably could not possibly be a more basic HTTP question, but I am very new to web development and I do not even know the right question to ask (evidenced by the fact that googling has not helped).

What I have: an AWS server with an Elastic Beanstalk environment set up.  I have successfully compiled, uploaded, and run a simple "Hello World" program to the environment using Eclipse.

What I want to do: pass the server a number via HTTP request and have the server give me back an HTTP response containing the square of that number.  On the back end, I want a simple Java class to do the squaring.  (Of course, the goal is to be able to pass more complicated data to the server and have more sophisticated Java code on the back end for processing.)

What I think I need to do: create a Java Servlet to listen for and process the request.  I think (hope) the documentation is good enough that I can figure out the HTTPServlet API, but I can't answer a more basic question: how do you pass an HTTP request containing some elementary data, like a number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either GET, or POST (or PUT) your data. GET provides the data in the URL of the request, and will be displayed in the browser's address bar. POST data is provided as a separate request body.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

A simple GET would look like this:

http://example.com/server?number=4

You can make a POST using a browser extension such as PostMan:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Or you can do it from the command line using curl:

curl -X POST http://example.com/server -d'data'

Once the data is more complicated than a few variables, you probably want to use POST rather than GET. Also, you can start to think about what your requests are doing. GETs should only retrieve data from the server. If you modify or create data, then POST (or PUT) requests are the methods to use.

As your server becomes more complex, you probably want to start reading about REST.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, thanks!  I am going to experiment with some GET requests right away and follow up if I have trouble.  I have an immediate question about POST, though: how do you send one?  It looks like a GET request is sent by physically typing it into a browser's URL bar and hitting enter, but where do you put a POST request?

Comment: Edited post to include POST info